# Error "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated." in query with Date Fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to run a query that, given a product, his estimated duration and the date when the product was received returns the expiration date and the days until that expiration date. I already have another query doing exactly the same but using another table and it works fine, but for some reason with this one, I can't make it work and keep receiving the error "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated.". I've read a lot of answers here and tried various different things (check if I have null values, if all dates are typed correctly, using DateValue, ...) but none of them seems to work.

Can anybody help me?

The code I'm using is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT QueryMensalMov.PersonID, QueryMensalMov.[Nº pessoal] AS [Name], QueryMensalMov.Product, QueryMensalMov.Quantity, [ProductList].DurationDays, QueryMensalMov.Date, DateAdd("d",Nz([ProductList].[DurationDays],0),DateValue([Date])) AS ExpirationDate, DateDiff("d",Date(),DateAdd("d",Nz([ProductList].[DurationDays],0),Date)) AS Days
FROM [ProductList] INNER JOIN QueryMensalMov ON [ProductList].ProductID = QueryMensalMov.ProductID
WHERE ((([ProductList].DurationDays)>0) AND ((DateAdd("d",Nz([ProductList].[DurationDays],0),Date)) Between Date() And (Date()+90)));
```

The tables are:
QueryMensalMov

| PersonID | Nº pessoal | ProductID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Filipa | A | 20-05-2020 |
| 2 | Mark | B | 15-07-2021 |

Product List:

| ProductID | DurationDays |
| --- | --- |
| A | 30 |
| B | 90 |

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Advise not to use reserved words as names which can sometimes cause issues in query. `Name` is a reserved word. Either change it or enclose in [ ] and see if that helps. Provide sample data as text table in question.

Comment: @June7 please see edited question, already added the tables. Tried to put the [ ] in Name but it didn't change anything

Comment: You have another query doing these same date calculations and that works? I tested the query with your data and it works.

Comment: @June7 yes, I have another query but using another table. The table is very similar to this one. Do you have any idea of why this may be working with you and not with me? Maybe it was a problem with the data, as I just added here sample data, but I already checked all the dates so that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok already fixed it, to be honest it was a stupid mistake.

The table QueryMensalMov is actually a Query based in another table. The problem was that the field Date was in Date/Time Extended format, instead of just Date/Time. That was causing the problem as, obviously, he couldn't execute the DateAdd with that kind of Date.

Don't know if this may be useful to someone, because this was a stupid mistake, but here it is. Always check the formats of your tables!

Comment: As soon as I can do it (just tomorrow, I believe), I'll mark! Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `[Date]`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    QueryMensalMov.PersonID, 
    QueryMensalMov.[Nº pessoal] AS [Name], 
    QueryMensalMov.Product, 
    QueryMensalMov.Quantity, 
    [ProductList].DurationDays, 
    QueryMensalMov.Date, 
    DateAdd("d", Nz([ProductList].[DurationDays],0),DateValue([Date])) AS ExpirationDate, 
    DateDiff("d", Date(), DateAdd("d", Nz([ProductList].[DurationDays],0), [Date])) AS Days
FROM 
    [ProductList] 
INNER JOIN 
    QueryMensalMov 
    ON [ProductList].ProductID = QueryMensalMov.ProductID
WHERE 
    ([ProductList].DurationDays > 0) 
    AND 
    (DateAdd("d", Nz([ProductList].[DurationDays],0),[Date]) Between Date() And (Date()+90));
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. In fact the name of that field is OperationDate, instead of just Date (I had to translate the data, so it was easier to understand and changed the name). But everything to do with dates I already tried